# G is a graph with 100 vertices and $G \cong \overline{G}$. Is it possible that there is ONLY 1 vertex of valency 50 in G?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

As far as I understand, there exists such a graph, but I don't know if we can possibly prove its unicity as well.

Comment: @bof oh, I didn't notice that question when I was looking for it. Language barrier I suppose, thank you

Comment: The answer to that old question shows that a self-complementary graph of order $n$ contains an even number of vertices of degree $d$, **except** when $n=4k+1$ and $d=2k$.